# C# / Unity - How I can compare string variable?

Tags: c#, string, variables, unity-game-engine, compare

How I can compare string variable in first object with string in second object in Unity?
There is screenshots with my problem: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C7A243435ECAB1C0!2948&authkey=!ADg0Uh6Ih1cJKd8&ithint=folder%2cpng

Thanks for answer.

PlayerMove:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour {

Vector3 pos;
public float speed;
char mv;
string ObstacleTypePlayer;


void Start () {

    pos = transform.position;

}

void Update () {

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && mv != 'l')
        pos.x -= speed;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        pos.x += speed;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && mv != 'u')
        pos.y += speed;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) && mv != 'd')
        pos.y -= speed;


    transform.position = pos;
}


void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{

    if (col.CompareTag("obstacle"))
    {
        col.gameObject.GetComponent<Obstacle>().Move(true);
        print("obstacle");
    }

    if (col.gameObject.GetComponent<Obstacle>().ObstacleType == "big left") // not true, but if Obstacle.ObstacleType == "big left"
    {


        if (col.CompareTag("side_up"))
            NotMove('d');

        else if (col.CompareTag("side_down"))
            NotMove('u');

        else if (col.CompareTag("side_right"))
            NotMove('l');

    }

}

void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D col)
{

}


void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.CompareTag("side_up"))
        NotMove(' ');

    else if (col.CompareTag("side_down"))
        NotMove(' ');

    else if (col.CompareTag("side_right"))
        NotMove(' ');

}

char NotMove(char z)
{
    mv = z;
    return mv;
}

}
```

Obstacle:

```
Vector3 pos;
GameObject player;
bool move = false;
public string ObstacleType = "aaaa";

void Start () {
    player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
    pos = transform.position;
}
public bool Move(bool mo)
{
    if(mo)
        move = true; 
    return move;
}

void Update () {



    if (ObstacleType == "big left" && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        move = false;

    if (move)
        transform.position = player.transform.position;

}
```

Comment: Include your code *in the question*. You compare strings with `==` usually.

Comment: obja.TheString == objb.TheString

Comment: but compare with other object and script string

Comment: Since the problem seems to be not directly related to that compare, include the entire classes, not just snippets.

Comment: The only way to comunicate between scripts in diferent GameObjects in Unity is using "GameObject.SendMessage()"

Create a public GameObject in the script of one of yours GameObjects and atach the other gameObject to it in the editor. Then, send the string to a public method, for example : public void recieveString (string anyString). Now you can compare this string inside the other string.

Comment: @ORParga That is totally not what is needed in this case. This is about comparing a variable of another gameobjects script component with a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact same way as you called the `Move()` function:

```
col.gameObject.GetComponent<Obstacle>().ObstacleType == "big left"
```

Edit:
From what I can tell, you have your `Obstacle` gameobject that has some child objects. Each of them has it's own tag (`obstacle`, `side_up`, `side_down`, `side_right`) and colliders. Since the above code gives you a `NullReferenceException`, the only possible reason for me is that only the main object has the `Obstacle.cs` component, not the childs and therefore the above line fails.

Edit 2:
The line should be like this if only the parent should have the script on it:

```
col.transform.root.GetComponent<Obstacle>().ObstacleType == "big left"
```

Comment: I know, but it is error : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Assets/Scripts/PlayerMove.cs 46

Comment: I tried a long time ago. :D

Comment: That is the correct way of accessing the variable in the other script. If you get a NullReferenceException the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: But where, everything is right :D

Comment: You might want to add a `return;` at the end of  `if(col.compareTag("obstacle"))` to not check further or make the second block an `else if` since the colliding object can only have one tag.

Comment: @Adam if you get that exception for that line, then `col`, `col.gameObject`, or `col.gameObject.GetComponent<Obstacle>()` is `null`. Debug to find out which and then decide how to handle that situation.

Comment: Actually, I have the suspicion that not all of the obstacles (or rather all of their collidable parts) have that script on them.

Comment: I've edited my answer and included what I think is your problem.

Comment: I add code, but i dont understand :( I am newbie in unity develop.

Comment: Only parent object has ObstacleScript

Comment: So what i can do? :)

Comment: And that is exactly what is causing your problem. Is that parent object the root? If so, change the line to `col.transform.root.GetComponent<Obstacle>().ObstacleType == "big left"`.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @GunnarB. Can i contact you when i have some problem with unity? :) If not, never mind.

Comment: I suggest posting your questions public so everyone can see them.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. You are the best :) @GunnarB.

Comment: @Adam, if this answered your question then remember to accept it by clicking the tick!